# C# Console Application unexpectedly closing

Tags: c#, asynchronous, httpclient

I'm trying to program a basic authentication method for a console application, however it seems to be unexpectedly closing on input..

Code Example -

```
    private static async Task Auth()
    {
        try
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Verify authentication");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your 6 digit code: ");
            string AuthenticationKey = Console.ReadLine();

            if (AuthenticationKey != "")
            {

                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.anysiteexample.com"))
                    {
                        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                        {

                            string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                            if(result.Contains(AuthenticationKey))
                            {

                                Console.WriteLine("Successfully validated credentials, starting program...");
                                Setup();

                            }
                            if(!result.Contains(AuthenticationKey))
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Failed");
                                await Auth();
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            if (AuthenticationKey == "")
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Auth key is empty");
                await Auth();

            }
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error raised closing application...");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
```

if I enter nothing on Console.ReadLine() then it will successfully execute the else statement, however if I enter anything alphanumeric on Console.ReadLine() it will close unexpectedly with no exception? When overall it should process the httpclient request and then either of those if/else statements.

Comment: Change the method signature of 'Auth' to return 'Task' instead of 'void'. Returning 'void' from 'async' methods is a very bad practise and is used only for event handlers. Also, you lose the await context if you use 'void' and you can't catch and handle exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not up to speed on the newfangled `async`-without-`Task` (is it even a thing?  thought it was happening in C# 8) but you're making recursive calls to `Auth()`, an `async` operation, without awaiting, so the original thread is exiting.  Try awaiting those recursive calls (and return Task like @zhulien said if this isn't some new feature)

But really you shouldn't make recursive calls here - you should return false, maybe with an explanation, and let the calling code issue another call to `Auth()` if that's what you want.

Comment: That's not "newfangled", `async void` exists since the beginning of `async`. But it's in general a terrible idea because you can't await on that.

Comment: I thought there was a new feature where the `Task` is implicit but maybe I was just dreaming

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to avoid the recursive calls and just have a `while` loop for validating the key input:

```
async void Auth()
{
    try
    {
        string authenticationKey = null;
        while(string.IsNullOrEmpty(authenticationKey))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Verify authentication");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your 6 digit code: ");
            authenticationKey = Console.ReadLine();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(authenticationKey))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Auth key is empty");
                continue;
            }

            if (!await IsAuthenticated(authenticationKey))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to validate credentials.");
                authenticationKey = null;
                continue;
            }

            break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Successfully validated credentials, starting program...");
        Setup();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error raised closing application: {ex.Message}");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}

async Task<bool> IsAuthenticated(string key)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
        return false;

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.authentication.com/example"))
    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
    {
        string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return result.Contains(key);
    }
}
```